# Type 'UITextField' has no member 'textDidBeginEditingNotification'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

With Swift 4.1 getting following error!!!!

> Type 'UITextField' has no member 'textDidBeginEditingNotification'

> Type 'UITextField' has no member 'textDidChangeNotification'

My error code.

```
override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
      super.draw(rect)
      self.drawLine()
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBeginTextEdit), name: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification, object: self)
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didTextEditFinish), name: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: self)
}
```

Comment: The code in your question is for Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete in Xcode would probably uncover this too, but you have the notification names wrong. Try `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` and `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`.